# nexus s ICS access PC host local server (virtualhost) when plugged

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, android

My problem is the following: I have a nexus s with ICS & a debian laptop with a local apache server using virtualhost (like http://myaddress.local/). And I want to access my local server from my smartphone when the latter is plugged. A bit like when you access your host web server from a virtual machine running on your computer.

I hope I'm enough clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm thinking to solve this with an IPV6 setup.

A bit like a typical IPV4 dynamic host setup, but without the precarious router forwarding rules.